# Does Thermal Radiation From A Colder Object Get Absorbed By A Hotter Object?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, thermal-radiation

I believe the answer is no, and I will explain my perspective. I would specifically like for answers to address the flaws or merits in the reasoning I present, rather than name call or invoke "I said so" arguments to authority.

I will reference this diagram:
[image]

Assume two objects, one hotter than the other, near each other in a vacuum. Perhaps parallel plates for simplicity, each a blackbody.
For simplification, the radiation frequency densities under discussion will be divided into high or "hot" and low or "cold". We assume a large percentage of the energy of the hotter object resides in the "hot" portion with high frequency density, and a large percentage of the total energy of the cold object resides in the "cold" portion of the spectrum.

The arrows represent energy flows.
Radiation in from the cold object, exclusive to the low energy portion of the spectrum.
Radiation out from the hot object, in both the high and low energy portions.
Internal energy transfer in the hot object which creates radiation in the low energy portion of the spectrum instead of radiating out from the high energy portion.

These are the dynamics as I see it:

1. The radiation from the cold object can ONLY be absorbed in the low energy portion of the spectrum. Period. As fundamental to the laws of physics as you can get.
2. IF the low energy radiation is absorbed in as energy is lost from that portion of the spectrum, then this will prevent or block internal energy transfer. All as a matter of timing and resonance.
3. If energy is blocked from transferring from the high energy portion of the spectrum to the low, then that energy will be lost as radiation from the high energy spectrum rather than being cycled through the longer wavelengths/slower frequencies of the low energy portion.
4. Per the basic principles behind the Planck curve and S-B law, the higher energy portion of the spectrum radiates more energy, loses energy faster than the low energy portion.

Therefore, any radiation which happens to be absorbed due to fortuitous timing and resonance, from the cold object into the hot object, resulting in the hot object becoming hotter (AKA, a slower rate of energy loss AKA radiative greenhouse effect) will lead to the hot object losing more energy as radiation from the high energy end of the spectrum than the object's own equilbrium. AKA, energy will be lost faster.

The rate of energy out from the hot object, due to this effect, would be greater than the rate of energy in from the cold object. That is, the high energy density portion of the Planck curve "dominates" and there is no net transfer of energy from cold objects to hot object by radiation. No "slowed loss of heat".

I would now like to discuss necessary context to avoid fruitless discussion below.
Typically, the following equation is used to model the radiative greenhouse effect as a net heat flow of radiation:  Q = σ(T4b−T4g)
Derived of course from the S-B law.
It seems this equation is inappropriate to apply to purely radiative transfer in an open system. For example, this simple engineering calculator makes the point clearly: https://www.efunda.com/formulae/heat_transfer/radiation/calc_2bodies_enclosure.cfm
"This calculator assumes that both bodies are graybodies, whereas the third surface is needed for conservation of energy reasons. This equation is subject to the reciprocity condition for the 3-body problem, which guards against non-physical problems. Reciprocity requires that, if Object 1 is larger than Object 2, the surface area of Object 2 seen by Object 1 must be less than unity. This means that the view factor must be less than 1 (or more exactly, less than A2/A1)."
Leading to: "The two bodies are assumed to be fully enclosed by a third nonconducting body, such that all radiation energy hitting this third surface will immediately re-radiate back into the cavity."

This is because the S-B law is about blackbody radiation, not heat transfer. Q = σ(T4b−T4g) is not a principle of radiation, but derived mathematically when one assumes the following pattern of events

1. Radiation out from blackbodies with given heat (S-B law describing relationship of heat to radiation)
2. Net radiation (system property)
3. Radiation into blackbodies creating heat (S-B again)

Simplification -> Net heat

This is not appropriate given my thought experiment with dominance of the high energy portion of the Planck curve. If cold objects cannot add net energy to hot objects by radiation alone, then it means that there is not transitivity in the use of the S-B law. Point #3 above fails, and Q = σ(T4b−T4g) is an inappropriate mathematical simplification.

For context I will note that this premise has been upheld at least in part by neutral engineering textbooks, particularly prior to the 1980s (that is, S-B to net heat transfer is for closed systems only). You will NOT find this caveat on the application of Q = σ(T4b−T4g) in engineering textbooks that include non-sequitur references to greenhouse gasses in the introductory sections about radiative thermodynamics. This is blatant politicization. That sort of topic is beyond the scope of this question, however. Instead, we have reasonable doubt about the appropriateness of applying Q = σ(T4b−T4g) to an open radiative system. We should ignore the politics, but also discard the notion that modern textbooks are inherently authoritative on this question.

This leads to experimental evidence.

An appropriate experiment was conducted twice, improved the second time:

1. https://theblackdragonsite.wordpress.com/2019/12/30/greenplate-effect-it-does-not-happen/
2. https://www.thepostemail.com/2019/12/31/greenplate-effect-it-does-not-happen/

Each validates the interpretation of radiative thermodynamics I have discussed.

It would be appropriate to doubt the results of these experiments and their author. However, each time the experiments seem reasonably and rigorously set up. The data conforms to reasonable hypothetical expectations. Occam's razor suggests it would be simpler that the data is accurate than that it was an elaborate fake.

Therefore, the scientifically prudent reaction should be to conduct further experiments aiming to measure the dynamic I described at the beginning. It would be relatively easy to set up two plates and record their temperatures as well as measure the radiation spectra emitting from each.

I have not seen any such experiment conducted. Certainly not in an institutional setting.

I believe it would be prudent to doubt the radiative greenhouse effect until such a simple experiment is conducted which somehow validates the paradoxical notion that low energy radiation can add into a body with higher densities of radiation creating a net flow of heat that slows cooling.

To reiterate, I would hope for my assumptions to be addressed given how I've presented them. Reiteration of textbook answers that refuse to account for concerns I've addressed in this original body of text will not be sufficient. Passive or backhanded name calling should be interpreted as a non-scientific answer.

Other than that I welcome all answers that address the thoughts and concerns I have presented, for or against. Apologies for structuring the question as a thesis, however it is necessary to anticipate common inadequate answers in order to get constructive answers to the core question which is expressed in the title.

Comment: The definition of a blackbody, which is by definition ideal, is that it absorbs all light that is falling onto it. It does not matter that it is colder light that is falling on it. You are just wrong when you asserted that there would be any "prevent or block internal energy transfer." You do not understand what resonance means. Your long question is just starting from wrong premises.

Comment: Absorb means a few things here. Absorb and reemit can happen with poor resonance between the radiation wave and the object. This does not mean there is a net transfer of energy. You are wrong about internal flows of energy. The only condition under which energy wouldn't be blocked is if there was variable amplitude of the waveform. However, because of the speed of light, energy in the waveform is expressed as frequency density. The Planck curve has its shape for a reason. I do not believe you have addressed my question, only made the claim that I'm wrong.

Comment: To delve into the strange finality of your dismissive answer, would an object so hot that it emits white visible light still count as a blackbody? Of course what I'm trying to say is that the blackbody ideal pertains to the question of reflectivity, not the object's absolute ability to convert all radiation which hits it into heat.

Comment: "would an object so hot that it emits white visible light still count as a blackbody?" Yes, and every standard introductory textbook covers this fact. Heck, we do it as pre-university physics here.

Comment: It sounds like you are saying the only two things that can happen when radiation hits an object are reflection or absorption. Obviously the blackbody ideal precludes reflection. What about scattering? To argue that all radiation is absorbed to become heat in a blackbody is to ignore basic physics, as far as I can tell. See, when you leave out basic physics it makes be question the adequacy of your answer. There is still time to be more thorough.

Comment: In order to clarify my argument, since I'm not disingenuous and not trying to "win" through appeal to authority or being vague, allow me to explain. A body's Planck curve represents the collected energies of its molecules vibrating at different wavelengths. Incoming energy is absorbed if it is resonant with the electron states of particular molecules. Again, as per my original post, the Planck curve represents the distribution of these energy states in the body. Non-resonant energy isn't scattered or "re-scattered" from molecules. Blackbody will "receive" maybe not "absorb" radiation.

Comment: Finally, this isn't "my pet theory" of physics. Rather, this is physics as I remember it taught in the 1970s and which I have encountered in literature numerous times until recent years. It is perhaps incorrect, but it is mainstream physics. I would seek evidence of some sort addressing why it's incorrect. Or even reasoning explaining where I have erred in my understand. Blanket dismissals that fail to even address the argument are not sufficient.

Comment: Blackbody radiation is properly treated even way back in the 1900s. The pioneers were smart enough to know that there is scattering. Every good textbook covers the physical apparatus that approximates the ideal blackbody is a (spherical) cavity with just a small hole as the link to the outside world; the walls of the blackbody does not need to be ideal, so that it can scatter and reflect as much as it likes; with enough repeated reflections the light that fell in will be absorbed with certainty. We treat this in high school, so you have no excuse to be saying that 1970s taught it differently.

Comment: Even in the absence of the blackbody approximation we have Kirchhoff's law of radiation and so we know that for conditions of local thermodynamic equilibrium, which is most circumstances, the absorptivity of a body at each wavelength is equal to its emissivity. That does not change with temperature. So your claim that higher temperature objects reject photons from lower temperature objects appears nowhere in the physics literature. Not in the 1970's and not now.