# Why Is Applying The Stefan-Boltzmann Law To An Open Radiation System Considered "Mainstream Physics"

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, thermal-radiation

For reference: [Does Thermal Radiation From A Colder Object Get Absorbed By A Hotter Object?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/808364/does-thermal-radiation-from-a-colder-object-get-absorbed-by-a-hotter-object)

Closed by moderators for questioning climate science obliquely.

In textbooks throughout the 20th century, the use of Q = σ(T4b−T4g) as a derivation of the S-B Law applied to heat transfer between objects was qualified by a clear caveat that the derivation only applied in closed thermodynamic systems. This was standard physics in engineering textbooks. The S-B Law itself makes it clear why. There's a fourth power on the relationship between temperature and emissivity. Hotter objects radiate much faster than colder objects. In an open radiative system, a cold object cannot, through radiation, slow the loss of energy from the hot object due to that fourth power being dominant.

I understand the politicization, big money and institutional support for climate change in academic institutions and why this caveat on Q = σ(T4b−T4g) would be removed. It would certainly call the hypothesis of a radiative greenhouse effect by backflows of energy into doubt.

Is it appropriate for actual scientists, or the moderators of this site, to claim that a discussion of Q = σ(T4b−T4g) being inappropriate for an open radiative system to be "non-mainstream physics". It would seem to me that mainstream physics is precisely where one must turn to get an adequate answer to this question.

Or is this website compromised by unscientific, politically oriented moderators?

In other words. There is no "mainstream physics" here. Merely political officers bastardizing and adulterating science. Scoundrels.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about physics. Questions about the site should go to [meta], but rants disguised as questions should not.

Comment: I agree. Separate the moderation complaint from the science question, and the science question would be fine here. The OP is the one bringing politics in